# Mechanism of Acid Hydrolysis

Tags: hydrolysis, esters

I wanted to ask a question about acid catalysed hydrolysis.

I learnt in an introductory course to Physical Organic Chemistry that there are different ways that an ester can be hydrolysed acidically:

> $\ce{A_{AC}1}$ 
>   $\ce{A_{AC}2}$ 
>   $\ce{A_{AL}1}$ 
>   $\ce{A_{AL}2}$

There are different ways that esters can be hydrolysed:
– catalysis by acids (A) or bases (B)
– cleavage of acyl-oxy (AC) or alkyl-oxy (AL) bonds
– the molecularity of the key step (1 or 2).

Using Acids (A) there are 4 different ways to hydrolyse an ester using acid catalysis:

> $\ce{A_{AC}1}$ Cleavage of Acyl-Oxy Bond Unimolecular
>   $\ce{A_{AC}2}$ Cleavage of Acyl-Oxy Bond Dimolecular
>   $\ce{A_{AL}1}$ Cleavage of Alkyl-Oxy Bond Unimolecular
>   $\ce{A_{AL}2}$ Cleavage of Alkyl-Oxy Bond Dimolecular

An explanation can be found [here](https://science-blogs.ucoz.com/resources/notes/msc/theory/EsterHydrol.pdf).

But consider this question, with the marking scheme given below:
[image]

Our professor did not mention anything regarding how to choose which type of hydrolysis takes place. From this question, he states and goes further onto mention that either $\ce{A_{AC}1}$ or $\ce{A_{AC}2}$ can take place, but no other.

I'm looking at these structures and thinking

**Why can't $\ce{A_{AL}1}$ or $\ce{A_{AL}2}$ take place for these two? Why must it be the two given in them marking scheme?**

Comment: Perhaps you could explain in a few words what those mechanisms mean, or provide a reference. I think that's not too widely known.

Comment: @Karl Edit made. Reference added.

Comment: +1 , but I wouldn't add this as a P.S. People have a short attention span, they read five lines, find they don't get it, and move on. ;-)

Comment: @Karl edited it further so now it appears in the introduction rather than the end!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have read your explanation material more carefully! It clearly states that $A_{AL}2$ has not even been observed in acid hydrolysis due to water being a poor nucleophile in an $S_N2$ process. As for $A_{AL}1$, that only happens when the esterified radical can leave as a stable carbocation which, in this case methyl is a very very unstable carbocation.

Comment: Well if I am such a fool then I will learn today! Thanks very much this isn't actually my material but I read it so fast I couldn't actually make the point clear to myself! My apologies!